# In some devices (samsung , moto G3) vCard attachment with text is not working while send using android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, vcf-vcard

What I've done so far is :

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
    String pathToMyAttachedFile = "/myapp.vcf";
    File file = new File(root, pathToMyAttachedFile);
    if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
        return;
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent smsInbox = new Intent();
    smsInbox.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    smsInbox.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    smsInbox.putExtra("address", phoneno);//For sending to specific number
    smsInbox.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    //smsInbox.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,content);
    smsInbox.putExtra("sms_body",content);
           smsInbox.setType("text/x-vcard");
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(smsInbox,"send"));
```

If I do not add "address" key-value pair in intent then it would display a chooser asking to whom i want to send and then it works in all devices, like I'm able to send the text + VCard attachment. but I need to add address key as I want to send v-card with text to particular number but then it doesn't work.
I have been trying since long, I have tried all the solutions that I found on SO but nothing helped.